# Why does my Angular2 app integration tests (JUNIT) time out?

Tags: amazon-ec2, angular, selenium-chromedriver

I have a NG1 application served by a Wildfly 8.x backend; our integration tests are written in JUnit; we validate only for Chrome, using Chromedriver. Our sandboxes are MacBook Pro / El Capitan, and out CI box is an AWS EC2 running AWS Linux driven by Jenkins.

The NG1 integration tests run just fine on our sandboxes and the CI box (Jenkins). The tests on the CI box use a headless driver in conjunction with a xvfb frame buffer.

We are porting it to NG2. The porting effort had just began by using the instructions on the Angular.io upgrade guide. We now have the NG1 application running as a child of the NG2 root; just for kicks, we added two simple NG2 components, downgraded to NG1 and shown as siblings of the application view, nothing fancy.

The ported application integration tests run just fine on our sandboxes but fail in the CI box, with the symptom being a FluentWait timeout, for all tests!

I've found a number of suggestions to set  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null, as for instance here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87. Unfortunately this, and all other incantations, have not worked.

I would love to have some suggestions to help me with this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to upgrade the server tech stack where the integration tests were running:

- chromedriver: upgraded from 2.13 to 2.22
- chrome: upgraded from 41 to 53

Sadly, there is no documentation anywhere suggesting this.